# apache beam: how to override source parquet file with updated data

Tags: apache-beam, parquet

I have a beam pipeline written in python that reads two parquet files: `state` and `updates`. The pipeline keeps the current data "state" in the `state` file, reads a `updates` file and it will update the `state` file (possibly adding new rows) with the content of `updates`. Ideally my pipeline should overwrite the state file so that next time my pipeline runs with new updates I am comparing them with the most recent state.
Here is my issue. My starting file is called `state.parquet` after my pipeline ends, it won't override the file but it will create a new file called `state-00000-of-00001.parquet`. This makes me realise that this is probably not a really good idea to do this, because when the file will grow I could have the output file sharded across multiple separate files, and will cause problems.

What would be a better approach to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can give your files an execution id suffix such as `state-run0001-00000-of-0000x.parquet` and `update-run0002-00000-of-0000x.parquet`. Use the file names such as `state-run0001` and `update-run0002` as inputs of your pipelines. Then write the output to `state-run0002-00000-of-0000x.parquet`.

You just need to keep track of the execution id `run000x` to schedule your jobs.

Comment: probably didn't explain this clearly, but the point is that i don't want to keeptrack of the execution id, instead I want to override every time the same file. So that next time it runs I can just read it with the same file name. Is there a neat way to do it? or maybe is it a bad idea?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea. If something crashes or is canceled, your files could be left in an unknown state. What I have done before is save the list of files, trigger the job that writes new ones, and once everything completes, the previous files are wiped. Plus, trying to write to a single file will kill a lot of potential parallelisms.

Comment: got it, i think you have a good point. I will do what suggested.